# calculate percentage and split value

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a simple product page with multiple options. Each time an option is select the values are posted to a php. There is one option that calculates a extra fee based on the total

This is the problem,
Once an option is selected all the calculations are done in the backend, the % is added and returned which works perfectly. but i would like to show the total + % separately within the span tag. but it works for the first value and the rest are incorrect

so lets say the user clicks on `Day 1` which has a 10% extra

- The calculation is done and the 10% is added to the total on the backend php file.
- I do an extra calculation based on the total returned, subtract the %
  from the total and display it
- If the total is 198 (this includes the 10% added when clicked), it
  should show Day 1 180,00+18,00(10%) Day 2 180,00+36,00(20%) Day 3
  180,00+54,00

On the code i have written, it calculates only the clicked value correctly and rest is incorrect.. also each time i click it recalculates and show a different value.

Unfortunately i cannot edit the php file, so i have to work with the total which is returned in JavaScript. 
So each time the user clicks on an option it calculates the total

I'm not sure if this can be done, but any help will appreciated.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'calculation.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: option_data,
  success: function(total) {
    $('.total').each((index, item) => {
      const dateRef = +($(item).attr("data-ref")); //percentage                              
      var grabtot = thistotal.split(" ")[2].replace(',', '.');
      var theid = $(item).attr("id");
      var amount = (dateRef / 100) * grabtot;
      var without_percentage = parseFloat(grabtot) - parseFloat(amount);
      $('#' + theid).html("+ € " + amount.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="radio">
    <label class="img2">
      <input type="radio" class="radio" style="display:none;" name="option[979]" value="2497">
      <span>
        <h3>Day 1</h3>
        <p>
          <span class="total" id="del-1" data-ref="10.00"></span>
        </p>
      </span>            
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="radio">
    <label class="img2">
      <input type="radio" class="radio" style="display:none;" name="option[980]" value="2597">
      <span>
        <h3>Day 5</h3>
        <p> 
          <span class="total" id="del-2" data-ref="20.00"></span>
        </p>
      </span>            
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="radio">
    <label class="img2">
      <input type="radio" class="radio" style="display:none;" name="option[959]" value="2407">
      <span>
        <h3>Day 7</h3>
        <p> 
          <span class="total" id="del-3" data-ref="30.00"></span>
        </p>
      </span>            
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT**

what will calculation.php return?

It actually booking system. The form will have cost of the product, packing, delivery and return days

- so if the cost of the book is 10,00
- packing 3,00
- delivery 5,00
- return days, percentage value which is selected. So if 1 day is
  selected the amount will be 20% of the sum

eg: 10+3+5 = 18
     charge for day 1 20% from 18 which is 3.6

total returned will be 21.6

the function will be called every time an option is clicked

Comment: You talk too much about what your site should do, but too less about what your problem is. Further you don't say much, what your `calculation.php` will return and you show nothing at which point your `ajax` will be executed. Please share some more informations about your problem or [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @UfguFugullu like i have mentioned in the question, i cannot modify any values inside the php files. i have updated the question to explain what is returned and how

Comment: What will your php return (json, xml, csv, plain text)? How will it be formatted? Why do you have other values in your edit as on your original question above? Is it possible to select multiple products? So much questions open, please try to explain your problem in one sentence.

Comment: @UfguFugullu it returns pain text.. just only one single value. i explained how the values inside the php work. so it returns the total. have a look at this http://demo.marketinsg.com/oc2_demosite1/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=42 you wil notice each time an option is selected it recalculate the total. Mine is somewhat similar. But i want it to split the total show it in the return date. So the user will know the breakdown. Please check this image https://ibb.co/X51Nz3v  on the returns option i want to show the total without% + %values.. so the sum should be equal to the total